# ASIHTTPRequest login page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, authentication, https

I try to make an iphone application that can login to the web application that use the https securing the user information.Now i am stuck in the login page. I don't know how to check the real account in the website of user when logging in by my application. I got the response only 200 even if i put the wrong account.

here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)clickOK:(id)sender {

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.freelancer.com/users/login.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
[request setDelegate:self]; 
request.shouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge = YES; 

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:usernameField.text forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:passwordField.text forKey:@"passwd"];


request.timeOutSeconds = 30; 

[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestLoginFailed:)];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestLoginFinished:)];
[request startAsynchronous];

}


- (void)requestLoginFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
//notify user
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error sending request to the server" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

}

- (void)requestLoginFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
int statusCode = [request responseStatusCode];
NSString *statusMessage = [request responseStatusMessage];

NSLog(@"StatusCode: %d", statusCode);
NSLog(@"StatusMessage: %@", statusMessage);

}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to check the real account of this website and keep user login?

Thanks for any help

Comment: is "ASIAuthenticationDialog.m" the file that the Obj-C code you posted from? Can you tell us exactly where the error occurred?

Answer (score 0):

You've started something Asynchronously

```
[request startAsynchronous];
```

And then just expected it to return something straight away:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[request responseString]);
NSLog(@"%d",[request responseStatusCode]);
```

You need to put something like this:

```
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(didFinishRequest:)];
```

And then move your NSLogs and any other stuff that leeches off of the response into that method.

Comment: Can any one advice me how to make user stay login when close app and then open it again and how to make another need the authentication? I familiar with php that use session_start(); how about Objective c

Comment: You need to look at the applicationWillEnterBackground and applicationDidEnterForeground methods. Basically in the first method you'll want to save any user data to NSUserDefaults and in the second one you'll want to read that data and re-login.

Comment: How can i check the authentication of user, i tried something as followed and NSLog the responseStatusCode it still 200 with whatever i put in the text field.