# HTTPS Basic authentication

Tags: iphone, objective-c, basic-authentication

I try to authenticate user with username and password But in the `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` method it doesn't go to an `else` even if i put a wrong username or password. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)clickOK:(id)sender {

if ([[usernameField text] length] < 1 || [[passwordField text] length] < 1) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" message:@"Neither the username nor password may be empty!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    return;
}
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.freelancer.com/users/login.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                            timeoutInterval:10];    
NSLog(@"ispost");
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", usernameField.text, passwordField.text];
[request setHTTPBody:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (!theConnection) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"Could not login!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    return;
}

-(BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace{ 

return YES; 
}
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{

if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
    NSURLCredential *newCredential;
    newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:usernameField.text
                                               password:passwordField.text
                                            persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
    NSLog(@"credential created");
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential
           forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
     NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge"); 
} else {
    [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    NSLog(@"Invalid Username or Password");

    UIAlertView *userNameAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Invalid credentials. Please check your login details  !" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
    [userNameAlert show];

}
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
NSLog(@"Got response: %@", response);

responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
 }

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[responseData appendData:data];

return;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
[responseData release];
[connection release];
// Show error message
NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
      [error localizedDescription],
      [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
// Use responseData
NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[responseData length]);
[responseData release];
[connection release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge method like this :

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{

if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
        NSURLCredential *newCredential;
    newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:usernameField.text
                                               password:passwordField.text
                                            persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
    NSLog(@"credential created");
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");    
} else {
    NSLog(@"previous authentication failure");
    UIAlertView *userNameAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Invalid credentials. Please check your login details  !" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
    [userNameAlert show];

}
```

and the clickOk method to this :

```
- (IBAction)clickOK:(id)sender {

        if ([[usernameField text] length] < 1 || [[passwordField text] length] < 1) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" message:@"Neither the username nor password may be empty!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            return;
        }
        NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.webdav.org/auth-basic/"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                    timeoutInterval:10];    
        NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [theConnection start];
    }
 }
```

Comment: it stil the same, This time it doesn't work through `if` what i did wrong?

Comment: The URL you are using is not correct, it should be : `code` https://www.freelancer.com/users/login.php

Comment: i change it as your suggestion but it still the same

Comment: Please clarify what doesn't work like you think it should. Does it work when username and password are correct ?

Comment: i think it should check username and password when i put the right one it should authenticate user and allow user to go to other page but if user put the wrong username or password it should alert "invalid username or password" and can not access to any other page. i am new in iphone development. Can you suggest me what i want is match with what i did or i need to add any method.

Comment: The `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` method is a match with what you want it to do. If this is not what is happening when you test the app then the error is probably in the code setting up the `NSURLConnection`. So i would need to see more of you project to see what might be the error.

Comment: From my editting as above, it's all my code. it doesn't show any error but the `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` doesn't alert the invalid username or password

Comment: did you change the editing to reflect the most recent code ? The code above does not use the correct URL from what i see.

Comment: oops, sorry i forgot to change that one, here are all my code now

Comment: it's still work through the 'didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge' without checking correct or incorrect the username and password. Can you tell me what i did wrong or any sample code?

Comment: plz post the complete project online if you want me to be able to see where you got it wrong

Comment: [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?nabkomrzo8pvq71) there is link to download my project.

Comment: From looking at your project i see you mixed up 2 things : asking the user to provide the username and the password on one end and the application sending the username and password to the server when the server signals that the request is for a secured resource. So you need to store the username and password somewhere in your app in you `clickOK` method, but you do not login to the site. The `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` gets called when the URL you are asking for is a secured URL (like the URL to see bids for a project).

Comment: i decide to save the username and password in coredata but i don't know how do i check that is the real account in the website before save it. Can you advice me or any sample code??

Comment: the problem is that the freelance.com site is not using Basic Authentication to protect access, if it were you would see a dialog box popup in the browser asking you to provide username and password , but that is not the case. Instead freelance.com shows a webpage that shows a form in which you can provide the login details. [Here](http://test.webdav.org/auth-basic/) is a testsite that uses Basic Authentication and [here](http://test.webdav.org/)is the info on username and password.

Comment: i updated my answer above with fully working code that i copied from my changes to your Auth project code.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, the code that you update above is the basic authentication right? if so freelancer.com can't use it right?

Comment: freelancer.com does not use Basic Authentication so you are not able to use the `(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge` approach. Maybe you should look at `ASIHTTPRequest` instead, docs are [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) and look especially at _Handling HTTP Authentication_

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried to use the ASIHTTPRequest before but i also don't know how to check the real account. i got the response only 200 even if i put the wrong account. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10983882/1449381) is my link of my question before.